# База данных и Objective для тестирования

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Готовлю приложение для тестирования сотрудников. 
Будет база вопросов с 3-5 вариантами ответов на каждый (в зависимости от специализации вопроса).
То есть мне нужно создать массив с тремя составляющими - вопрос, метка о правильности выбора варианта ответа и правильный ответ.

Не могу разобраться с NSDictionary - можно ли это реализовать в нем?

Или сделать три массива NSArray - первый с вопросами, второй с ответами, третий - с метками правильных вариантов?

Или еще есть варианты?

Comment: Если под словом "база" у Вас подразумевается БД то в нее и пишите

Comment: объясню - будет определенное количество вопросов - к каждому вопросу будет метка правильного варианта и соответственное количество правильных ответов

Comment: список следующих вопросов строится динамически в зависимости от ответов данных на предыдущие вопросы?

Comment: нет. вопросы выбираются случайным способом, без какой либо привязки друг к другу

Answer (score 1):

Советую создать `.plist`, там будет:

`Dictionary` вопросов (`questions`) с полями:

```
    ID с типом //какой удобней
    question с типом Array //массив вопросов

В question:
    ID с типом //какой удобней
    text с типом String //текст вопроса
    answers с типом Dictionary //коллекция ответов

В answers:
    ID с типом //какой удобней
    answer типом Array //массив ответов на вопрос

В answer:
    ID с типом //какой удобней
    text с типом String //текст ответа
    isRight с типом BOOL //тип ответа(если YES, то ответ правильный, если NO, то не правильный)нужно для проверки на правильность
```

далее читаем доку по работе с .plist для вытаскивания нужных полей.
Это все конечно "к примеру", есть и другие варианты.

P.S. ID не обязательно, можно использовать только индекс массива или коллекции.